# Get position of array in Onclick

Tags: android, arrays, listview, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a dialog box that shows some data which has been retrieved from another java class that gets it from my Azure SQL database.

After i declare my `String array` in my current class, i try a `.get(position)` but it gives me an error : `Cannot resolve symbol get(int)`

Here is my `getData.java`

```
public class GetData {
Connection connect;
String ConnectionResult = "";
Boolean isSuccess = false;


public List<Map<String,String>> doInBackground() {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    try
    {
        ConnectionHelper conStr=new ConnectionHelper();
        connect =conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
        if (connect == null)
        {
            ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Change below query according to your own database.
            String query = "select * from cc_rail";
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()){
                Map<String,String> datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                datanum.put("NAME",rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                datanum.put("PRICE",rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                datanum.put("RANGE",rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                datanum.put("SUPPLIER",rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                datanum.put("SIZE",rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }


            ConnectionResult = " successful";
            isSuccess=true;
            connect.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return data;
}
```

and here is my `mainactivity.java` which populates my list view and my dialog code:

```
            List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;
            GetValence mydata =new GetValence();
            MyData= mydata.doInBackground();
           final String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","SIZE","SUPPLIER","RANGE" };

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.size_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);



    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        private ImageView icon;
        private String fullName,partyName;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /** To change selected state view */
            view.setSelected(true);
            String Slecteditem = fromwhere.get(position);
```

i get my error by `String Slecteditem = fromwhere.get(position);`

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: @D-johnAnshani `Cannot resolve symbol get(int)`

Comment: @Mohammedis271 i have added an answer please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromWhere` is an array and it doesn't have `.get()` Method since you are using an array then you have to access the value by index directly like `formWhere[position]` If do you want to use an arrayList instead of normal array then you can use `.get()` Method